# React video element performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a performance issue with  element in React.

In my app I'm establishing webrtc connection between 2 users and render their streams in  elements so they can see each other. I create them using js DOM manipulation like so:

```
video = document.createElement('video')

video.id = 'native-video-' + that.getGlobalID()
video.autoplay = true
video.controls = false
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(wrStream)
if (local) {
  video.muted = true
}
parentElement.appendChild(video)
```

Everything is working fine, users can't see each other without any problem. However when I started rewriting my app to React I've ran into a performance issue when rendering  elements. Videos stutter really badly so it's more of a slideshow than realtime streaming (it varies from ~1fps to ~10fps). Im using following code (nothing fancy i belive):

```
renderLocalStream () {
  return (
    <video ref='videoPlayer'
      id={'native-video-' + this.state.localStream.getGlobalID()}
      src={this.state.localStream.getStreamSrc()} >
    </video>
  )
}
```

I've checked how often component updates because I thought that it may keep updaing really fast- producing stutter, however it turned out that it updates only once so thats not the issue here.

I have a feeling like I'm missing something really simple but I just can't figure it out. Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: What browser are you using? I created a quick example using ReactJS and displaying an mp4 using the `<video>` tag and the video displays fine (https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/46807/). I'm assuming your issue is either browser related or possibly related to the webrtc thing you mentioned (not familiar with that).

Comment: I've changed my src to mp4 file from your example and it is working just fine so  you're right, it must be directly related to using webrtc in react.

Comment: Have you looked at the react-webrtc module? It is a WIP but it may give you some ideas as to what the culprit may be. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webrtc)

Comment: I have a similar problem in my react app with webRTC  but instead of src i am using the srcObject method and passing it the mediaStream.
It is visible only in small windows(like almost 30vw or smaller).
Could you tell if thats the case with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the autoplay on the video element in th react code which causes this stutter effect in Chrome.

Comment: Yes you're right, adding autoPlay to <video> component fixed my issue :) Do you know why would that create stutter?

Comment: chrome is behaving weird here. It should not play the video at all in that case. But I couldn't find a bug despite a couple of people here hitting the issue in the last two months

Comment: I see. Anyway thanks for solving this one for me, I was trying to figure it out for god knows how long...

Comment: I was also experiencing this behavior with reagent from clojurescript, a react wrapper. I just want make sure that people know this fix also applies to them as well.